# Azure SQL DWH Design For Micro-batch Update

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I Just need one opinion regarding database design using Azure SQl DWH

Here is the current scenario:

We are building a DWH system using Azure SQL DWH whose source is from Timeseries DB that captures Sensor related information for every 15 Sec. Now we have data-bricks cluster running for every 2-min which aggregates those data and stores it in our Fact tables. 
For all the fact tables i have kept the index type: Clustered Column Store Index with Round Robin distribution

Similarly our Dimension tables are populated from Service bus topics. These topics receives all the Insert/Update/Delete records and that is captured with the help of Azure Web jobs that continuously pool those topics and make necessary entries into our dimension tables.

For all the dimension tables i have kept the index type: Clustered Index(For business key) with Round Robin distribution..

Do you think this is a good design for Azure SQl DWH where records are getting updated in the target in a micro batch fashion. Also there are some Power BI reports running on those tables in DWH using Direct Query Mode for near-real time analytics.

Please suggest if there is any alternative approach

Comment: This question should not have been voted down. It contains a legitimate question about best use of the product. The question is likely to be of use to others.

Answer (score 2):

You will get much better performance by changing your Fact distribution to HASH() and your Dimension distribution to Replicate.

Round robin tables will force a redistribution on subsequent queries, and replication will avoid cross node data shuffles before joins.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback,and i'll make the changes to the table design. So with respect to data load and real time reporting requirement will this changes be enough. Do i need to scale Azure SQL DWH DWU?

Comment: I can't answer that question without knowing a lot more about your configuration and data ... especially since i don't know which DWU you are using :)

Comment: Rereading the question, how are you handling the movement of data from Databricks and web jobs? Make sure you're using the Data Warehouse connector from Databricks (not the SQL Server connector), and don't run single row insert / update / delete statements from your web job. In both cases, process the data as micro-batches not single rows.